# Is there a way to incorporate a Mojolicious::Controller with a MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm working with zabbix and writing an interface to interact with the zabbix api. Since zabbix exposes a jsonrpc interface I decided to use MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service.  The problem I'm running into is that I'm now faced with interacting with other services written using Mojolicious::Controllers where they're expecting a Mojolicious::Controller objects.  There is no Mojolicious::Controller object available when using MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service.

```
my $obj = $rpc_obj->register(
               'retrieve',
               sub {
                    # do stuff
               },
               { with_mojo_tx => 1 }
);
```

That registers a route called 'retrieve'. When the route is accessed and the anonymous
subroutine is run, the subroutine has access only to the Mojo::Transaction::HTTP object.

So, I don't have access to the app for using plugins and the stash and other things that Mojolicious offers. Is there a way to incorporate Mojolicious::Controller with MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service?

I could rewrite it to use a Mojolicious::Controller but I'm trying to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to use [MojoX::JSON::RPC::Dispatcher](http://search.cpan.org/~henryykt/MojoX-JSON-RPC-0.03-2/lib/MojoX/JSON/RPC/Dispatcher.pm), as it inherits all attributes from [Mojolicious::Controller](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-2.94/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm)

**SYNOPSIS:**

```
# lib/your-application.pm

use base 'Mojolicious';
use MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service;

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    my $svc = MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service->new;

    $svc->register(
        'sum',
        sub {
            my @params = @_;
            my $sum = 0;
            $sum += $_ for @params;
            return $sum;
        }
    );

    $self->plugin(
        'json_rpc_dispatcher',
        services => {
           '/jsonrpc' => $svc
        }
    );
}
```

---

[UPDATE]
**Hook Example:**

```
package Application;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';
use Application::Firewall;

# This method will run once at server start
sub startup {
    my $app = shift;

    # Routes
    my $r = $app->routes;

    # Validation Middleware
    $app->hook(
        before_dispatch => sub {
            my $self = shift;
            my $data = $self->req->params->to_hash;
            my $vald = Application::Firewall->new($data);

            # mojolicious bug at the time of coding
            delete $data->{""} if defined $data->{""};

            $app->{input} = {};

            if ( keys %{$data} ) {

                # validation the submitted data
                unless ( $vald->validate( keys %{$data} ) ) {
                    $self->render(
                        text   => join( "", @{ $vald->errors } ),
                        status => 500
                    );
                    return 0;
                }

                # Helper (optional)
                # create a helper to get access to the transformed data
                # if your validation rules had/has filters
                # Note! due to a bug in the params function we must do this
                # (... i know, so what)
                $app->{input} = {
                    map { $_ => $vald->{fields}->{$_}->{value} }
                      keys %{ $vald->{fields} }
                };

            }

            return 1;
        }
    );

    # Normal route to controller * with auto-matic input validation *
    $r->route('/')->to(
        cb => sub {
            my $self = shift;
            $self->render(
                text => 'Hello ' . ( $app->{input}->{foobar} || 'World' ),
                status => 200
            );
        }
    );
}

1;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. The problem I was having was that when the 'sum' route is executed there is no access to the Controller. Basically I wanted to do some some authorization before executing the route.  So, now I'm trying adding a hook to $self->app as $self->app->hook( before_dispatch => sub { ... } );  in the application so I won't need to access the Mojolicious::Controller in  'sum()'.   http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-2.94/lib/Mojolicious.pm#hook

Comment: @jmcneirney - When you use `my $self = shift;` then is should be just `$self->hook`... or then if you use `my $app = shift;`, then it is `$app->hook`, but I am not sure why you use `$self->app->hook`..?